# Not able to perform login with facebook other than my userid

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to create login with facebook with my application.The problem is I'm able to access the application with my facebook userid but not with the others.It say am error occured. Below is my code,Could anyone please check upon it and let me know what I am doing wrong?

```
public function fbverifyAction(){

        $facebook = new Facebook(array(
                  'appId'  => 'xxxxxx',
                  'secret' => 'xxxxxxxxx',
                   'cookie' => false,
           ));
         $user = $facebook->getUser();   
         if ($user) {
                 $uid = $facebook->getUser();
         $me = $facebook->api('/me');
                 $db = Zend_Registry::get('dbadapter');
          $select = new Zend_Db_Select($db);    
          $select = $db->select();
          $select = $db->select();
          $select->from(array('owner' => 'owner'),array             ('idowner','username','firstname','password','fb_config'));
          $select->where('owner.fb_config = ?',$me['id']);
          $stmt = $select->query();
          $result = $stmt->fetchAll();
        if(count($result) > 0)
        {
           $usr = $result[0]['username'];
            $pass = $result[0]['password'];
            $url1 = $this->address."access/verify?   username=$usr&password=$pass";
         }
        else
        {    
            $uid = $facebook->getUser();
                     $permissions = $facebook->api(
                                    '/me/permissions ',
                                            'GET',
                                    array(
                                 'access_token' => $facebook->getAccessToken()
                                ));
                             $perdetails['firstname'] =$permissions['first_name'];
                            $perdetails['lastname']=$permissions['last_name'];
                            $perdetails['username']=$permissions['username'];
                            $perdetails['fb_config']=$permissions['id'];
                            $db->insert('owner', $perdetails);

        }

            echo "<script type='text/javascript'>top.location.href = '$url1';</script>"; 
                            }
        else {
           echo '<script>top.location.href="'.$facebook->getLoginUrl().'";</script>';

       }
    }
```

Comment: Is really `am error occured` the exact and complete error message?

Comment: yes it says An error occurred. Please try again later.can you please help me out

Comment: Have you set the redirect URL in your facebook app? It needs to match the one you are using in the authenticate oauth request. I've seen the rather non verbose "An error occurred" message in this situation.

Comment: hi,i have set the uRL in site URL section of facebook app.I'm not using authenticate oauth request in the Action.Do I need to access that.If so could u please let me know how can I achieve this